# Cant retrieve form data with ajax post request in django

Tags: django, ajax

> I am trying to retrieve form data {orderId, email} in views.py from a ajax post request. I have used the csrf_token. But the variables get None in httpResponse.
>   Below is the views.py code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def track(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        orderId = request.POST.get('order_id')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        return HttpResponse(f"{orderId} and {email}")
```

Below is the ajax post request:

```
    $('#trackerForm').submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#items').empty();
         var formData = {

            'order_id': $('input[name=order_id]').val(),
            'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
             encode: true
         };
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/shop/track/',
            data: 'formData'
         })
         .done(function(data){
            console.log(formData);
            console.log(data);
         })

    });
```

> I am getting the output of console.log(formData). But I am not getting the out of console.log(data) {the response from views.py} it shows on console screen as  "  None and None" , which means orderId and email have values None. Please respond to it. It will be a great help.

Comment: as `data` you are passing a string instead of the object

Answer (score -1):

it's not good idea to exempt csrf.
instead you could use of JQuery form `submit()` or `serialize()`.
in your template and for the `form` give it an id, then inside the ajax function, access that form with jquery element selection by ID. as follow:

```
$.ajax({
        url: ajax_link,
        data: $('#your_form_id').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            }
        });
```

in your `views.py` you could figure-out if the request is ajax call, by using 
`if request.is_ajax():`. but there is no need to submit a form. 
you can pass any data as a python `dict()` (or a javascript `object`) with the ajax method. e.g. in the ajax function you can have: `data: {'email': $('#email_field').val(), 'oreder_id': $('#oreder_id').val() }`

the code inside of your `views.py: orderId = request.POST.get('order_id'), email = request.POST.get('email')` is ok, but it works if you have two input fields with attribute `name`, equal to `email` and `order_id` in the form you're submitting.